# Send user that got kicked the reason why they got kick

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

The only code I have is this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",

    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`You coudn't kick that member!`);
        }
    },
};
```

Good Morning. So I'm trying to get it to message the person that got kicked the reason why they got kicked. (`!kick user reason`) I want it so the bot DMs the person what the reason was but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You would only need to add the following:

```js
const reason = args.splice(1).join(` `) || 'Not specified';
memberTarget.send(`You have been kicked: \nReason: ${reason}`)
```

```
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",

    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();

        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            const reason = args.splice(1).join(` `) || 'Not specified';
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
            memberTarget.send(`You have been kicked: \nReason: ${reason}`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`You coudn't kick that member!`);
        }
    },
};
```

The `const reason = args.splice(1).join(` `) || 'Not specified';` defines the 'reason' property, if there isn't a reason, it defaults to 'Not specified'.

`memberTarget.send(`You have been kicked: \nReason: ${reason}`)`
Just sends the message to the targeted member.

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I see that you are getting the [`target`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) using `message.mentions.users` and getting the [`memberTarget`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) from the guild's cache. You should avoid this and use `message.mentions.members`.

---

You'll have to use the [`send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) method of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), but since it returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you'll have to catch any errors. (e.g: the bot cannot DM the member)

```js
// You should do some sanity checks in case you haven't. You don't want everyone to be able to kick members using the bot.

// Getting the first member in message.mentions.members.
const target = message.mentions.members.first();
// Making sure that target is defined.
if (!target) return message.channel.send('Please mention a member to kick.');
// Making sure a reason is provided. (args[0] is the mention)
if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('Please provide a reason.');
// Making sure the bot can kick the target.
if (!target.kickable) return message.channel.send('Couldn\'t kick the target.');

// Trying to send a message to the target, notifying them that they got kicked, and catching any errors.
target.send(`You have been kicked from ${message.guild.name} for ${args.slice(1, 2000).join(' ')}`).catch(console.error).finally(() => {
    // After the message was sent successfully or failed to be sent, we kick the target and catch any errors.
    target.kick(`Kicked by ${message.author.tag} for ${args.slice(1, 2000).join(' ')}}.`).then(() => {
        message.channel.send(`${target.user.tag} has been kicked for ${args.slice(1, 2000).join(' ')}.`);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
        message.channel.send(`Something went wrong...`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This is working kick command with reason made by me (you can try it):-
It has every validation you should have in a kick command

````js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

exports.kick = async(message , prefix , client) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('Missing Permission! You need to have `KICK_MEMBERS` permissions in order kick this member.')

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('Missing Permission! I need to have `KICK_MEMBERS` permissions to kick this member.')

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();

    if(!member){
      let err = "```css\n[ Agrument Error : You Have not mentioned the user on first args. ]\n```\n\n"

      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(`${client.user.username} Help Manual` , client.user.displayAvatarURL({format : "png"}))
      .setTitle(`${message.guild.name}`)
      .setDescription(err)
      .addField('Help Command:' , `\`\`\`\n${prefix}kick @user#0001 Reason\n\`\`\``)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor('RED')
      return message.channel.send(embed)
    }

    if(args[0] != `<@!${member.id}>`){

      let err = "```css\n[ Agrument Error : You Have not mentioned the user on first args. ]\n```"

      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(`${client.user.username} Help Manual` , client.user.displayAvatarURL({format : "png"}))
      .setTitle(`${message.guild.name}`)
      .setDescription(err)
      .addField('Help Command:' , `\`\`\`\n${prefix}kick @user#0001 Reason\n\`\`\``)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setColor('RED')
      return message.channel.send(embed)
    }

    if(member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send(`Why? No Just Say Why Do you want to kick yourself?`)

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    if(!reason || reason.length <= 1){
      reason = "No Reason Was Provided."
    }

    if(!member.kickable){
      return message.channel.send(`I Don't Have Permissions to Kick ${member.user.username}`)
    }

    member.kick().then(() => {
      return message.channel.send(`Successfully Kicked ${member.user.username} for Reason ==> \`${reason}\``)
    }).catch(() => {
      return message.channel.send(`I Don't Have Permissions to Kick ${member.user.username}`)
    })
}
````

Comment: You're downvoted because it doesn't answer the question. OP wanted to send a DM to the kicked member.